# How to speed up AnimationDrawable?

Tags: android, performance, android-animation, android-imageview

I have used AnimationDrawable in Android project, where animation-list consists of three drawawble-resources (1920x1080 PNG image files). The code works fine and animation plays, but it is awfully slow, as it should be rapid (like gunshot animation). It does not make difference if android:duration is set to "10" or "500". Tested on Galaxy S4.

Are there any tweaks that can be done, like preloading imageresources etc.? If not, are there any alternatives to AnimationDrawable to do frame animation?

Comment: Reduce the size of your image? That is the first thing that comes to my mind

Comment: That is not what I would like to do, as in high-end/high-resolution devices the image quality would suffer.

Comment: When you used Traceview and systrace to determine where your problem lies, what did you learn?

Comment: I would say, if you can keep parts of the images that are stationary separate and only animate the parts that are moving.

Comment: @CommonsWare I did not fully understand what you meant, but yes, I have used systrace to measure runtimes from my application. Seems like drawing image is slow and my question was is there any way to speed it up?

Comment: "I have used systrace to measure runtimes from my application" -- that does not match your question, though. For example, you state that "seems like drawing image is slow", but then ask about pre-loading resources, which is not related to drawing times. If the time truly is in drawing logic, then see if hardware acceleration was somehow disabled.

Comment: @CommonsWare you are right, the pre-loading example was a bad one. Hardware acceleration is enabled in problematic view, so that is not the cause. Is there anything else I can check, or is it simply so, that AnimationDrawable can't handle fast paced animations with bigger images?

Comment: I am sure that `AnimationDrawable` was not designed with 1080p images in mind. That being said, the drawing time is unlikely to be tied to `AnimationDrawable` specifically. Try running a performance test of calling `setImageResource()` on an `ImageView` using one of your frames as the resource. If you find that the time for that is comparable to the per-frame time of `AnimationDrawable`, then it is rendering 1080p images in general. If, OTOH, `setImageResource()` is quick, perhaps you could create your own animation outside of `AnimationDrawable`.

Comment: Facing the same problem. At one place where the image view is larger than the other one, the animation is running as expected but in the other image view its running so slow. Has anyone found any solution yet?